# Passing NSString from one method to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I've got myself some of a newbie problem.

I got this method to determine the zip code where the iPhone is located, based on GPS coordinates. Reverse Geocoding. My method works, I know this, since it has no problem writing out the correct zip code to a label.

But I need this zip code to be stored in a string that I can use inside a method I use to compose a SMS.

Anyone can help me with that?

Tell me if an source code is necessary! (Just not currently sitting on my work comp)

Clearly i've been misunderstood, should have posted som code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;


    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            **postalCode** = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            placemark.postalCode];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

Here i try to save the zip code inside the NSString named postalCode (highlighted with "**")

I try to load it again in sms composer

```
-(void)displaySMSComposerSheet
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;


    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          placemark.postalCode];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1220", nil];
    picker.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dog %@", (placemark.)postalCode];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

only prints out in the SMS window:
Dog (null)
And i'm sure i have the coordinates, they get printed out in the output.

Hope this helps to understand the question better

Comment: Just post the code of yours (How you have displayed the code to `UILabel`) and elaborate your question, if possible.

Comment: Answering for fun but voting “Not a real question”. In your code you already have the zip on a string to set the label, so what is the problem?

Comment: Would it help to store the string in an ivar? You can then access it everywhere in your instance.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, i have no problem to get it to write it into a label, i need it to store it in a NSString, so i can use it in SMSComposer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface SomeController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end


@implementation SomeController

-(void) trackUpdates
{    
    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations 
{
    CLGeocoder* gcrev = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [gcrev reverseGeocodeLocation:[locations lastObject] 
                completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         CLPlacemark* revMark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSString *zip = [revMark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"ZIP"];
         NSLog(@"%@",zip);
         // ... do something with the zip, store in an ivar, call a method, etc.
     }];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self trackUpdates];
}

@end
```